# GWT: Character encoding umlauts

Tags: gwt, encoding, diacritics

I want to set a text in a label:

```
labelDemnaechst.setText(" Demnächst fällig:");
```

On the output in the application the characters "ä" are displayed wrong.

How can I display them well?

Comment: Which browser? What's the content encoding? when you inspect the compiled output what do you see, umlauts or some garbage?

Comment: Google chrome, because it is an GWT application.

The content encoding? In the applicationname.gwt.xml I wrote 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

I take a look at a example project in the web and there they wrote "lÃ¶schen" instead of "löschen"
That works.... 
What should I write for the umlauts "ä" "ü" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well you have to encode your special charactars to Unicode. You can finde a list of the representive Unicode characters [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Your examle would look like this:

```
    labelDemnaechst.setText("Demn\u00E4lachst f\u00E4llig:");
```

Hope this helps, if noone has a better solution.

Appendix:

Thanks Thomas for your tipp, you really have to change the format in which eclipse safes it's source files. Per default it uses something like Cp1252. If you change it to UTF-8, your example works correct. (So Demnächst is written correctly).

You can edit the safing format, if you right-click on your file --> Preferences. 
[image]

Comment: You should really do this at the project or (even better) workspace level, rather than down to the file level.

Comment: probably, do you know where I can change that, so it automatically safes all new projects files in UTF-8?

Comment: @thomas-broyer : I disagree that it's better to do it at the workspace level. Workspace settings are local to that specific workspace, meaning other project members with different settings (and unfortunately the workspace setting does [not default to UTF-8](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108668)) will get issues. In contrast, when stored on the project level, these settings get shared in version control with all project members.

Answer (score 6):

GWT assumes all source files are encoded in UTF-8 (and this is why you see *lÃ¶schen* if you open them with an editor that interprets them as Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1).

GWT also generates UTF-8-encoded files, so your web server should serve them as UTF-8 (or don't specify an encoding at all, to let browsers "sniff" it) **and** your HTML host page should be served in UTF-8 too (best is to put a `<meta charset=utf-8>` at the beginning of your `<head>`).

If a `\u00E4` in Java is displayed correctly in the browser, then you're probably in the first case, where your source files are not encoded in UTF-8.

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Troubleshooting.html#International_characters_don't_display_correctly

Comment: thanks, I edited my anserer so it the java file gets safed correctyl

Answer (score 2):

To get UTF-8 encoding for your entire workspace, go to `Window -> Preferences`. In the pop-up start typing `encoding`. Now you should have `Content Types, Workspace, CSS Files, HTML Files, XML Files` as result. In content Types you can type UTF-8 in the Default encoding text box, for the other elements you can just select the encoding in their respective listboxes.

Then check the encoding for your project in `Project -> Properties -> Resource`.

Detailed instruction with pictures can be found here:

http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/

Cheers

Comment: This is actually the best answer. You really should set encoding on the project level to make sure it get's shared with other project members. Thanks for linking to my blog BTW  :)

Answer (score 0):

what i did:
open the file with notepad (Windows Explorer),
and save it with the option UFT-8 instead of proposed ANSI.

Encoding the project to UTF-8 didn't work (for me)

Cheerio

Answer (score 0):

Use iso-8859-1 (western europe) character set instead of UTF-8.