# Javascript FileReader readAsText function not understaning utf-8 encoding characters like ä and ö

Tags: javascript, csv, encoding, utf-8, filereader

I have tried searching this a lot and nothing helped me. I have an import from csv feature and javascript code reads the csv content line by line. The characters ä,ö etc are just not recognized. FileReader readAsText has default encoding utf-8 but in this case it is not for some reason working. Here is my code.

```
            reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = (e) =>
              result = e.target.result
              console.log result
              # file content
              fileContent = result.split("\r")

            reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0))
```

I have tried defining encoding like below and whatever I put there couldn't help me.

```
encoding = "UTF-8"
reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0), encoding)
```

Comment: Have you saved the csv file as UTF-8?

Comment: In mac I only see an option 'Comma Separated Values (.csv) and that's how the csv is saved

Comment: Please provide us a raw ASCII sample of the saving with those characters. Or you can check yourself if it is valid UTF-8 encoding or not.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa if you mean the text, something like this is the output 
"Ymp�rist�oppi
T�m�n puun rungon tyvi muuttuu vanhemmiten tummaksi ja pitkitt�isuurteiseksi, muuten kuori on valkoinen. Lehti on kolmiomainen ja pitk�k�rkinen ja sen laidat ovat kahteen kertaan sahalaitaiset. Vanhan puun oksat riippuvat ja n�ytt�vyytens� takia se on valittu Suomen kansallispuuksi."

Comment: Doesn't look like UTF-8

Comment: I'm stuck on the same problem. I'm loading some Spanish and readAsText replaces all accented characters with ? I'm using Eclipse and can't change that as I'm writing  javascript within a GWT framework. I've made sure all Eclipse encoding is set to UTF-8 as discussed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698932/gwt-character-encoding-umlauts)

Answer (score 11):

I got this to work by using ISO Latin 4 encoding.

```
reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0), 'ISO-8859-4');
```

That should work for you but remember to use this particular encoding just for some scandinavian characters.

Comment: In my case the ñ character didn't work out.
I used encoding 'ISO-8859-3' and it worked.