# Ckeditor drag and drop txt files

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ckeditor

I have the following which works in a normal text area, as soon as the textarea is turned into a CKEditor instance it no longer works I assume down to the dyanmic creation of CKEditor, so is it possible to achieve this?

```
<textarea id="drop_zone">Drop files here</textarea>


    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(event) {            
        document.getElementById('drop_zone').value = event.target.result;
    }        
    reader.readAsText(files[0],"UTF-8");
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `textarea` is not turned into CKEditor instance. Neither CKEditor replaces `textarea`. The editor resides next to `textarea` in DOM.

So the following wrong assumption

> as soon as the textarea is turned into a CKEditor instance it no longer works

is the root of the problem because when you call `CKEDITOR.replace( idOfTextarea )`, CKEditor hides `<textarea>` in DOM and creates editor structure next to it (inspect DOM with devtools to see it). As a result, all the listeners like

```
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

lose their meaning because they are attached to the `<textarea>` which is hidden while you drop the file into CKEditor, which is a totally different thing in DOM.

There's an [official sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html) about general drag&drop and file uploads. You may also use the editor API ([`editor#paste`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) event) to to something like this

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        editor.insertText( event.target.result );
    }

    reader.readAsText( evt.data.dataTransfer.getFile( 0 ), "UTF-8" );
} );
```

just make sure that you use the latest CKEditor 4.x.

Comment: this works brilliantly thank you, however some of my files have german characters. I thought UTF-8 would of avoided that. they are being placed in ckeditor as �

Comment: @Philwn Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443080/javascript-filereader-readastext-function-not-understaning-utf-8-encoding-charac?lq=1