# GWT arabic rendering

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, uibinder

I have a problem with my sidebar items when I set the item text with arabic text the output looks like  ������� and not rendered properly

```
LIElement item1=new SideBarItem().addSideBarItem("fa fa-fw fa-dashboard","العملاء","index.html");//here is the problem
    sideBar.appendChild(item1);
    sideBar.appendChild(new SideBarItem().addSideBarItem("fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o","Charts","charts.html"));
    sideBar.appendChild(new SideBarItem().addSideBarItem("fa fa-fw fa-table","Tables","Tables.html"));
```

this is the function I use

```
public LIElement addSideBarItem(String icon, String text,String target){
    anc.setInnerHTML("<i class=\"" + icon + "\"></i> " + text);

    anc.setTarget(target);
    return sideBarListItem;
}
```

so how to set the inner text of an element or widget as Arabic String 
for example setTitle("عربي");

Comment: Are **all** your files encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: yes my project.gwt.xml and my html page are both encoded to UTF-8

Comment: Thanks Thomas the only thing that was not encoded to UTF-8 was eclipse resources for the project

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the format in which eclipse saves it's source files
this link helped me
[GWT: Character encoding umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698932/gwt-character-encoding-umlauts)